# Number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

My code seems to look perfectly fine... I've been looking at it for the past half hour or so...

```
$dept_id = $_POST['dept'];
$id = $_POST['moduleCode'];
$name = $_POST['moduleName'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO ts_module
                (id,
                name,
                dept_id)
                VALUES 
                (:id,
                :name,
                dept_id)";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':id' => $id,':name' => $name,':dept_id' => $dept_id ) );
var_dump($stm->errorInfo());
```

Comment: You're missing a colon `:dept_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: Number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
You have to count number of tokens and compare it to number of bound variables. **They doesn't match.**

Please, try to solve such typo-like problems without employing the power of Stackoverflow.